# Different uri for PATCH vs PUT when changing uri slug

Tags: rest, api-design, restful-url, http-put, http-patch

In a proper REST API implementation, imagine I'm writing an API to let the user modify a uri slug, such as changing `/acme/first` to be `/acme/second`.

Depending if I'm submitting a partial record (`patch`) or the whole record (`put`) that currently represents `first`, should the uri vary?

For example:

```
PUT /acme/second
{ [...], "current-slug": "first", "color": "blue" }
```

Put against the *new* uri because `put` means "this goes here."

vs.

```
PATCH /acme/first
{ "new-slug": "second", "color": "blue" }
```

Patch against the *old* uri because `patch` means "modify the thing that's here."

**I suspect this is an edge case, but interesting because virtually all documentation happens to show the same uri for a `put` vs `patch` action, though obviously `post` is generally a different uri.**

Comment: PUT is a poor choice because it won't invalidate cached copies of the first uri.

Comment: @EricStein Excellent point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is definitely a little bit of an edge case. One obvious HTTP method to do this, is actually just the HTTP [`MOVE`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#section-9.9) method. This method comes from WebDAV, but it should work everywhere.

```
MOVE /acme/first HTTP/1.1
Destination: /acme/second
```

This would be my top recommendation, because it fits the problem so well.

What's weird with *either* `PATCH` or `PUT` is that they are both expecting to update the resource *at the target uri*, but the result of the operation is more similar to `DELETE` because it removes the resource (and creates a new one somewhere else).

Because of this, I would be inclined to suggest to use neither for this case. This is enough of an edge case to warrant a special `POST` request.

But yea... `MOVE` is perfect. Any HTTP client or server that doesn't deeply understand `MOVE` semantics should treat it similar to `POST` (unsafe, not idempotent).

Comment: Using WebDAV's `move` is an interesting idea. I deliberately added `color` above though to invalidate it. Theoretically, I want to change two properties: `id` / `slug` and `color`. Move makes sense, but efficiency says this is one continuous operation as it's filled out in one user-facing form (let's say). I think your suggestion of `post` (as a "generic CRUD operations that aren't clearly something else") is probably the only viable option.